# What should I do if I wanted an url with '#name' as name of the page, with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to figure out how obtain www.namedomain.com/#namepage with angular

Javascript:

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){ 

    $routeProvider.when("/",{
            templateUrl: "/templates/register/testingblock.htm",
            controller: "MainCTRL"
        })
        .when("/#name",{
            templateUrl: "/testingBlock.htm",
            controller: "MainCTRL"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`location.hash()` will return you `'#namepage'` and I think it will help you.

Comment: With Angular? I need to set up the routing of several pages, how can location.hash() help me?

Comment: It is clear from your question that How you want to perform routing but location.hash() will provide you current loacation ,so that you can perform further routing based on loaction

Comment: @ShubhamNigam: this is not how routing in angular works.

Comment: I don't want to retrieve the name of the page after '#', but I wish writing a page like www.domain.com/#namepage and landing #namepage page

Comment: Try to remove html5Mode because html5 mode doesnot accept '#' url try to remove that html5 line then  write www.domain.com/#namepage .. I think it will solve it out